# prototype for 'Figure::Figure()' does not match any in class 'Figure'

Tags: c++, qt

Could you help me understand what I'm doing wrongly.
I have NetBeans, MinGW compiler, and Qt library included.

****Figure.h****

```
class Figure: public QObject{ //18
    Q_OBJECT
        public:
                Figure(); //32               
};
```

**Figure.cpp**

```
Figure:: Figure(){   // 16              
}
```

Error messages are:

```
Figure.h:18:7: error: candidates are: Figure::Figure(const Figure&)
Figure.h:32:17: error:                 Figure::Figure()
Figure.cpp:16:1: error: prototype for 'Figure::Figure()' does not match any in class    'Figure'
```

By the way, I have tried to follow this `Figure(const Figure&)` pattern. It didn't work.

Added later (more code as was asked):

**Figure.h**

```
#ifndef FIGURE_H
#define FIGURE_H
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QFrame>
#include <initializer_list>

#pragma once

enum colours {RED, GREEN, BLUE, YELLOW, MAGENTA};

class Figure: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
        public:
                int shape[4][4]; 
        private:                
                int previous_shape;
                int current_shape;
                int current_x; 
                int current_y; 
                int previous_x;
                int previous_y;
                colours colour;     

        public:
                Figure();                
                int testint;
                int test[2];                
                void change_figure();
                void roll_back(); 
                void set_coordinates(int direction);
                void set_colour();
                void rotate();
                int get_x();
                int get_y();
                int* get_shape();

//        signals:
//                void transmitInfo();            
};
```

**Figure.cpp**

```
#include "Figure.h"
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <QtGui> 
#include <QtGui/QApplication> 
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
template <class T>

Figure:: Figure(){         

        //shape = {{1, 1}, {1, 1}};
        previous_shape = 1;
        current_shape = 1;
        current_x = 5;
        current_y = 5;
        previous_x = 5;
        previous_y =5; 
        colour = RED;   
}
```

Comment: How is Q_OBJECT defined?

Comment: Can you update your post and include the entire Figure.h and Figure.cpp?

Comment: @Scott Jones, Q_OBJECT is a Qt macros.

Comment: Well at your figure.h, it is lacking an #endif.

Comment: @kenrogers, Ok. Not entire, but a bit more code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is that `template <class T>` doing there in your `.cpp` file right before `Figure::Figure()` definition? Your `Figure` class is not declared as a template in `.h` file.

Comment: Nor can it be, `QObject` derived class cannot support class templates because of the `moc`.